# Find centroids in the dataset before performing clustering or without using any clustering algorithms

Tags: numpy, cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning, centroid

Being clustering an unsupervised problem in Machine Learning field, I will have a system where the input is an unlabeled dataset where the number of clusters is basically unknown.

I can of course find out the centroid(s) available in the dataset by applying clustering algorithms such as hierarchical clustering or DBSCAN or k-means etc by guessing the number of clusters.

**How can I find out the centroid(s) without performing or using any clustering algorithms?**

**Note:** I will be using these centroids as common points to calculate euclidean distances of two different datasets. Till now centroid gives more accurate predicted euclidean distances of the data points of N different datasets where the points are not shared to calculate the distance but just there pairwise distances with the common points.

**Also, any suggestions on using any other statistical measure which can find common points that might perform better than using centroid as common points?**

I would really appreciate if someone can answer or guide me to the solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about looking for dense subgraphs in your data? and using the points that belong to each dense subgraph to find a potential centroid

Comment: Hey @yannziselman, how do you suggest to look for dense subgraphs and find potential centroid? :) TIA

Comment: https://github.com/varungohil/Densest-Subgraph-Discovery

Comment: *"How can I find out the centroid(s) without performing or using any clustering algorithms?"* Wouldn't finding the unknown centroids be, in effect, a clustering algorithm?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, the problem is cannot know the number of clusters beforehand but I need to find out the cluster centers. The system I am designing is for common users who cannot understand the parameter values of clustering algorithms such bandwidth,epsilon,minPts of existing DBSCAN, MeanShift clustering algorithm. Users also wont be able to get cluster_no using elbow or other methods.  The reason I need centroids without knowing the no of clusters is because I want to use some common points to calculate pairwise distances between the points where the points are not from the same dataset.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, Let say A1 and A2 are data points of dataset A while B1 and B2 are those of dataset B. I need to get pairwise distances between A1B1,A2B1,A1B2,A2B2 without sharing the A1,A2,B1,B2 as they are sensitive values. So I am considering 2 artificial common points X1,X2 in both dataset and calculate the distances. For e.g. A1B2 is getting calculated using distance(A1,X1), distance(A1,X2), distance(B2,X1),distance(B2,X2). But if this common points X1 and X2 are random then the results are very bad and till now using centroids as those common points has given better results. Any help?